# Use alias in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webpack, server, phaser-framework

I am translating this with the google translator so if something is misspelled then sorry
It turns out that I have a phaser game that is compiled with webpack to a dist folder, but the entire project itself is inside apache, that is, it is already public, so to speak, so I would like to be able to configure with a .htaccess that all requests to the game for example `http://localhost/game/index.html` will show me the document of `game/dist/index.html` but without redirecting me.

I know that I can do this with an Alias in the `httpd.conf` but I would like to do it with an .htaccess inside the `game` folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in `/game/.htaccess` using mod_rewrite to internally rewrite all requests to a `dist` subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/(.*)
RewriteRule !dist/ dist/%1 [L]
```

This basically rewrites all requests that are not already for the `dist` subdirectory to the `dist` subdirectory.

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. the URL-path that follows `/game/`.